# File permissions for Ubuntu image on CircleCI

Tags: python, continuous-integration, subprocess, yaml, circleci

I'm new to using CircleCI. I have a Python script that I use to call some os commands, like

```
path = "/Users/Name/Dev"
os.makedirs(path)

cmds = ["cd path", "touch hello.txt"]
cmd = "; ".join(cmds)
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

However, I'm hit with a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: /Users/Name/Dev` whenver I try to access a directory. Also can't cd, can't write, etc. This is while running on CircleCI, but works fine on my personal machine.

Any ideas for what I can try? How do I fix these permission problems on the VM?

The config.yml setup for CircleCI looks something like this:

```
  build-and-test:
    machine:
      resource_class: large
      image: ubuntu-****
    environment:
      CI_VARIABLE: "8.0.1"
    working_directory: ~/repo
```

Comment: You're using a Mac, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Mac

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because you're trying to create a set of folders `Users/Name/Dev` in the `/` of the CircleCI machine. You shouldn't be able to do that due to security constraints (probably permission to create folders and write stuff).

A better approach to that would be to create a folder `Dev` in the home folder using environment variables, something like this:

```
path = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'Dev')
os.makedirs(path)

cmds = ["cd '" + path + "'", "touch hello.txt"]
cmd = "; ".join(cmds)
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

That way you would always get a writable folder for the user, as it'd always be the home folder.